# Cython errors: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cython_helpers)

Tags: cython

I want to cythonize some functions in my code, but I kept ending up with many errors. I would like some help as I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
I have the following files to test cython:

cython_helpers.pyx:

```
cdef public void initcython_helpers():
    pass

def func_cython_wrapper(list a):
    return func_cython(a)

cpdef func_cython(list a):
    cdef int i
    cdef int j
    for i in range(len(a)):
        j += i
        
    return j
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension("cython_helpers", sources=["cython_helpers.pyx"])

setup(
    name="cython_helpers",
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext, language_level=3),
)
```

test_cython.py:

```
import cython_helpers

my_list = [1, 2, 3]
a = cython_helpers.func_cython_wrapper(my_list)
print(a)
```

I run:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

and get:

```
running build_ext
copying build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/cython_helpers.cpython-39-darwin.so ->
```

Finally I get:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cython_helpers)
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong based on what you show here: 1) Make sure you're building with the same version of Python you run it with; 2) make sure you're not renaming any files - leave the names that Cython creates; 3) Cython itself should create the module export function - I'm slightly worried that `initcython_helpers` is your attempt to do so manually, and possibly you might be getting in Cython's way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I would run the following line in a command line:

```
$ python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

but then try to run *test_cython.py* in a Spyder console. Not sure how to put it correctly, but Spyder doesn't use the newly compiled code. It utilises the old one. So a workaround is to close the Console tab in Spyder and open a new one after every build.